# Solve the integral $\int \frac{3\cos x+7\sin x}{5\sin x+2\cos x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I think it is necessary to do the replacement. That's just what?

$$\int \frac{3\cos x+7\sin x}{5\sin x+2\cos x} dx$$

Comment: I suggest you look at the solutions to this question, here on stack exchange: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1219016/indefinite-integral-with-sin-and-cos/1219098#1219098

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

Write $$3\cos x+7\sin x=A(5\sin x+2\cos x)+B\dfrac{d(5\sin x+2\cos x)}{dx}$$ where $A,B$ are arbitrary constants.

Compare the coefficients of $\cos x,\sin x$ to determine $A,B$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** you can substitute $t = tan(\frac{x}{2})$