# Reference request: Where is this trigonometric identity found?

Tags: trigonometry, reference-request, mobius-transformation, linear-fractional-transformation

[Note that this is a reference request; I already know a couple of routine ways to prove the identity.]

In April I posted [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1219016/indefinite-integral-with-sin-and-cos/1219317#1219317).  Then yesterday I had occasion to conjecture that in general
$$
\left(\frac{p\sin x + q\cos x}{r\sin x + s\cos x} = \frac{p\tan x + q}{r\tan x + s} \right) = a + b \tan(x - \varphi)
$$
for some $a,b,\varphi$ depending on $p,q,r,s$.

The special case I posted in April was one in which $p=s$ and $r=q$ and there was nothing in it I thought was messy.  On this one I'm getting $\tan\varphi=r/s$ (that part's easy) and $a$ and $b$ are slightly messy rational functions of $p,q,r,s$. (Among the values of $\varphi$ whose tangent is $r/s$ I know of no reason to prefer any particular one.)

**Are this identity and the specifics of the function $$p,q,r,s\mapsto a,b,\varphi \tag 1$$ universally known and out there in the literature somewhere?**

And did I miss some elegant pattern in $(1)$?

Comment: Just a random guess here, but I'd suggest seeing if you could make something from the tangent angle subtraction formula

Comment: What does that equal sign between the parenthesis mean??

Comment: @ASKASK : That gets you a sort of inverse of the mapping in $(1)$, but I don't know that it shows the inverse is surjective without getting just as messy as the rational functions I mention above. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MASL : I just means those two things are trivially equal and the equality that is the focus of attention here is the other one. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$and my gut says this whole thing should be an utter triviality instead of something messy, so I'm probably missing something that will be obvious by hindsisght. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I could guess that, but then I think you know better than writing weird things like that.  Trivial -assuming it is- itself doesn't make it equivalent to *well-know* and your editing is confusing.

Comment: @MASL : It seemed almost certain that if I didn't write it that way, someone would think I was asking how to prove the first equality.  Things like that happen here. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$a+b\tan(x-\phi)=a+\frac{b\tan x-b\tan\phi}{1+\tan x\tan\phi}$$
$$=\frac{\tan x(b-a\tan \phi)+(a-b\tan \phi)}{1+\tan x\tan \phi}$$

We can equate this to $$\frac{\frac ps\tan x+\frac qs}{\frac rs\tan x+1}$$ if we allow $$\frac ps=b-a\tan \phi$$ $$\frac qs=a-b\tan \phi$$ and $$\frac rs=\tan \phi$$

Now, by eliminating $\tan \phi$ and solving simultaneously for $a$ and $b$,  we get $$a=\frac{rp-sq}{r^2-s^2}$$ $$b=\frac{rq-sp}{r^2-s^2}$$

Comment: +1.  ok so far, although I will come back to check this in detail only later.  However, this doesn't address the reference request. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find it in here:

Abramowitz, Milton; Stegun, Irene A., eds. (1972). Handbook of Mathematical Functions with Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables.

Comment: I just checked my copy of that book.  Unfortunately, there are no entries for the traditional trigonometric functions there, so this reference tip does not qualify for Michael's request.