# Reference request on some trigonometric identities

Tags: trigonometry, reference-request

[Reference request: Where is this trigonometric identity found?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425618/reference-request-where-is-this-trigonometric-identity-found)

Here I will somewhat extend this earlier question (linked above) that I asked.

\begin{align}
\frac{a\tan\theta+b}{c\tan\theta+d} = e\tan(\theta-\varphi) + g \tag 1 \\[10pt]
\frac{c\tan\theta + d}{a\tan\theta + b} = k\tan(\theta - \chi) + m \tag 2
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\text{where} \qquad e & = \frac{ad-bc}{c^2+d^2} \tag 3 \\[6pt]
g & = \frac{ac+bd}{c^2+d^2} \\[6pt]
\tan\varphi & = \frac c d \\[6pt]
\frac{a^2+b^2}{c^2+d^2} & = e^2+g^2 = \frac g m \tag 6 \\[10pt]
k & = \frac{bc - ad}{a^2+b^2} \tag 7 \\[6pt]
m & = \frac{ac+bd}{a^2+b^2} \\[6pt]
\tan\chi & = \frac a b \\[6pt]
\frac{c^2+d^2}{a^2+b^2} & = k^2+m^2 = \frac m g \tag{10} \\[15pt]
(e^2+g^2)(k^2+m^2) & = 1 \tag{11} \\[6pt]
\frac 1 e - \frac 1 k & = \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}{ad-bc} \tag{12}
\end{align}

It may be said that $(1)$ conjoined with $(3)$ through $(6)$ says the same thing as $(2)$ conjoined with $(7)$ through $(10)$.  However, this seeming redundancy makes it possible to state $(11)$ and $(12)$.

So my question is where if anywhere this is found in the literature and where does it intersect with what is known?  It's all elementary and easy to establish, and it has a nice pattern to it, but none of it was in Wikipedia's extensive "list of trigonometric identities" last time I looked at that.