# Solve integral $ \int \frac{dx}{( \sin x + 2 \cos x )^3}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Alright, so this one has been giving me nightmares for a couple of days now... I've tried the substitutes for $u = \tan \frac{x}{2}$ where you can substitute 
sin(x), cos(x) and dx accordingly and pretty much every possibility and combination that came to mind with them and still nothing. I mostly get stuck with a polynomial of the forth or sixth degree and can't really do anything from there. I've also looked up some integral calculator programs which gave me humongous solutions without steps of how to the program got there. Any hint appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: You can try writing $\sin(x)+2 \cos(x)=\sqrt{5}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \sin(x)+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \cos(x))$ And then assigning $\cos(A)$ to either $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ or $\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$ then assigning $\sin(A)$ to the remaining one. Trying to get you to use one of the sum/difference trig identities. Say we let $\cos(A)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$ and $\sin(A)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ Then we can write $\sin(x)+2 \cos(x)$ as $\sqrt{5}\cos(x-A)$ We can come back and solve for the constant $A$ later if we need to; we may not need to depending on our answer. So you should come to the following integral after this $\int \frac{1}{(\sqrt{5})^3} \sec^3(x-A)dx $ Let $u=x-A$ then $\frac{du}{dx}=1$ or $du=dx$ So you have $\frac{1}{5 \sqrt{5}} \int sec^3(u) du$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1219016/indefinite-integral-with-sin-and-cos/1219078#1219078 You can find this same method being used here. Different problem, but same method.

Comment: Alright i've done what you asked and got to the step \frac{1}{\sqrt{5} \int \frac{1}{( \sin X + \cos A )^3} don't really have a clue what to do from here

Comment: Updated my hint above.

Comment: Trigonometric identities:
$$
\sin(x)+2 \cos(x)=\sqrt 5 \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \sin x+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \cos x \right) = \sqrt 5\Big( \cos\varphi\sin x + \sin\varphi\cos x \Big)
$$
$$
= \sqrt 5 \sin(x+\varphi)
$$
where $\cos\varphi= \dfrac 1 {\sqrt 5}$ and $\sin\varphi = \dfrac 2{\sqrt 5}$. $\qquad$

Comment: Ive tried that one but i somehow get stuck afterwards and dont really know how to solve the given integral beyond that point...

Comment: @NxS try by parts. Also I did a sub above in my answer so the parts part is easier.

Answer (score 0):

As what randomgirl did by auxiliary angle, I am going to complete the solution for reference.

Letting $\alpha = \arctan (\frac{1}{2})$ changes the denominator into $$
\sin x+2 \cos x=\sqrt{5} \cos (x-\alpha)
$$
which convert the integral into
$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=\int \frac{d x}{(\sin x+2 \cos x)^{3}} \\
&=\int \frac{d x}{\sqrt{5}^{3} \cos ^{3}(x-\alpha)} \\
&=\frac{1}{5 \sqrt{5}} \int \sec ^{3}(x-\alpha) d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Using integration by parts yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \sec ^{3} y d y &=\int \sec y d(\tan y) \\
&=\sec y \tan y-\int \tan ^{2} y \sec y d y \\
&=\sec y \tan y-\int\left(\sec ^{2} y-1\right) \sec y d y \\
\int \sec ^{3} y d y &=\frac{1}{2}(\sec y \tan y+\ln |\sec y+\tan y|)+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Plugging back gives $$
\begin{aligned}
I &=\frac{1}{10 \sqrt{5}}(\sec (x-\alpha) \tan (x-\alpha)+\ln (\sec (x-\alpha)+\tan (x-\alpha))+C\\
&=\frac{1}{10 \sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{\sin (x-\alpha)}{\cos ^{2}(x-\alpha)}-\ln \left|\frac{1+\sin (x-\alpha)}{\cos (x-\alpha)}\right|\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$
For simplification, using
$$
\sin (x-\alpha) =\sin x \cos \alpha-\sin \alpha \cos x =\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(2 \sin x-\cos x)
$$
and $$\sin x+2 \cos x=\sqrt{5} \cos (x-\alpha),$$
we can conclude that
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
I & =\frac{1}{10 \sqrt{5}}\left[\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(2 \sin x-\cos x)}{\frac{1}{5}(\sin x+2 \cos x)^{2}}-\ln \left|\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(2 \sin x-\cos x)}{\left.\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \sin x+2 \cos x\right)}\right|\right]+C \\
& =\frac{1}{50}\left[\frac{2 \sin x-\cos x}{(\sin x+2 \cos x)^{2}}-2 \sqrt{5} \ln \left|\frac{2 \sin x-\cos x}{\sin x+2 \cos x}\right|\right]+C
\end{array}
$$

:|D Wish you enjoy the solution!